# ffmpeg drawtext on video in start

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I've to add declaimer in start of video for few seconds, horizontally center with green background, how can I do it with single command and overwrite the existing video without re-encoding

Comment: If you alter the visual content, you'll have to re-encode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to make a disclaimer image converted to a video clip, then you could merge the two videos into one sequence without-re-encoding.

note: The **image** video must have same resolution and framerate as **main** video. As much of both settings must match. Use a tool like [**`mediaInfo`**](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) to check output settings.

**(1)** Convert Intro (*"Disclaimer"*) image to video clip

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i intro.png -c:v libx264 -t 4 -pix_fmt yuv420p intro2.mp4
```

where : `t` = duration in seconds, `-r` = frames per second, `-loop 1` = loop image over frames...

**(2)** Combine Intro with Main video

You'll have to make a `.txt` file inside same folder as videos. Strangely just for *"No re-encode"* mode.
Put the following text into Notepad (or any basic text tool) and save as `files.txt`

(content of *files.txt*) :

```
file 'intro.mp4'
file 'main.mp4'
```

Then use this command to output a joined video...

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy final.mp4
```

Comment: I'm new to ffmpeg, how can I get framerates with PHP, and put it into this command `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i intro.png -c:v libx264 -t 4 -r 24 -pix_fmt yuv420p intro2.mp4`

Comment: @VC.One Just a small thing, but if you remove the `-r 24` output option and replace it with `-framerate 24` input option you can avoid the 25 fps (default) to 24 fps conversion.